# Script Directory Permissions Powershell

Tags: windows, permissions, powershell, windows-server-2016

Is there a way to clone a directory's permissions to a file, and then run that file on another server to recreate those permissions on the recreated structure.

I've got a script to create the directories:

```
New-Item -Path D:\superuser-data -ItemType directory
Net-Item -Path D:\superuser-data\documents -ItemType directory
Net-Item -Path D:\superuser-data\scripts -ItemType directory
```

I run that script then setup the permissions to the way I want them with AD accounts on Server A.

Then I want the ability to rerun that script on Server B and then run another script on Server B that sets the permissions to match what I did on Server A.

Comment: I'd highly recommend this module for convenience: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85 using only `get-acl` and `set-acl` can be very head-achy

Answer (score 1):

From here: https://seankilleen.com/2015/01/how-to-copy-ACL-Permissions-To-Folders-With-Powershell/

Powershell contains the commands `get-acl` and `set-acl`, and you can pipe them together:

```
Get-Acl -Path C:\Folder1 | Set-Acl -Path C:\Folder2
```

Those paths can be UNC or other appropriate path methods, so they should be able to work across networks.

**Update:**

Security Descriptors CAN be copied and stored. The following is not the most efficient process, his is the first time I've even tried doing this, but it is functional.

A few iteratively-refined Google searches brought me here: http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/replacing-ntfs-permissions-with-sddl-information

And here's the process.

1. **Capture** the ACL from the source computer:
   `$SDout = get-acl -path (source folder)`
2. **Store** the SDDL in the clipboard:
   `$SDout.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm('All') | clip.exe`
3. **Paste** into Notepad and move to the target computer.
4. **Copy** ONLY the single-line SDDL to the clipboard.
5. **Store** the source SDDL in a parameter:
   `$SDsource = '(paste the source SDDL here)'`
6. **Capture** the target ACL object in a parameter:
   `$SDtarget = get-acl -path (target folder)`
7. **Overwrite** the target's SDDL with the source's SDDL:
   `$SDtarget.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($SDsource)`
8. **Write** the modified ACL back to the target folder:
   `set-acl -Path (target folder) -ACLObject $SDtarget`

Checking properties now you should see the target folder has the same permissions as the source folder.

Comment: Can I store the results of Get-Acl into a file that set-acl can read in?"

`
Get-Acl D:\superuser-data\ | Out-File superuser-data.txt
cat superuser-data.txt | Set-Acl -Path D:\superuser2-data\`

Comment: The pipe uses PS' object system. Sending get-acl's output to a file loses the object-nature of the information, so you'll have to massage the data either when you export or when you import, or in-between.I tried simply storing the output in a file (out-file) and then importing it into a new varial (get-content) and the syntax was not understood by set-acl.

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured something out. Give me a few minutes to test.